# Pass *args directly to function

Tags: python

How can I pass *args from one function directly into another one called within it and maintain its functionality?

If I do it like this:

```
def parent(*args):
    child(args)

def child(*args):
    print(args)
```

I get this output:

```
>>> parent(1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> ((1, 2, 3, 4),)
```

but:

```
>>> child(1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

I want the parent function to print out the same as if I called the child function directly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just unpack them before you give it to the next function.

```
def parent(*args):
    child(*args)

def child(*args):
    print(args)
```